# Cannot open file - structure needs cleaning

Tags: filesystem

[image]

In the above image link posted, i have attached an error i am facing when trying to access a file. Point to note is that this file is in my 2 TB HDD whereas my ubuntu OS is in a different 500GB SSD. Can someone help me what to do with this?

It happens when I use GPU to train a machine learning model(intensive read write operations)

Comment: I unmounted the drive and tried e2fsck command. But the issue repeats after 2 or 3 days and every time i run this command the effected files are getting deleted, and nor recovered.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the filesystem on your 2TB drive is inconsistent. Try unmount the drive and do a fsck. Provide the output of the following commands if you need the exact commands:

```
lsblk
df -hPT
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite probable that the intense read and write operations which you mention are taking place **before** the kernel has time to flush data to your 2 TB drive.

If you find the answer from @xpk above not solving your problem, try to add some sleep/wait time between r/w requests to your machine learning software.

I am curious about this myself, please report back.